# Open source projects with good quality tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, open-source

I know there is a thread about open source projects with good code quality, but which projects have unit tests (With mocking) and are of a high quality?

Many Thanks

Comment: Community wiki please. This is more of a poll than a real question with a single correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASP .NET MVC](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) source contains extensive unit tests that uses Moq for mocking.

Comment: I really think this answer misses the spirit of the qusetion.  Referring to Microsoft as an open-source shop seems incredibly disingenuous.

Answer (score 1):

Most of them do have unit tests.

For example, I consider [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org) and the [Castle project](http://castleproject.org) the most prominent ones.  (Although I haven't examined Castle's code more closely yet, I know NHibernate has very nice unit tests.)

You can pull the source code from a public repository for both of them.

EDIT:
SubText also had nice unit tests when I last checked.

Answer (score 0):

[Gallio](http://gallio.org) is an OSS automation plateform for unit testing. Interestingly enough, it uses its own testing framework ([MbUnit](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=start)) to run its unit tests during the build process. It's an interesting form of dog fooding.

While unit tests make a moderate usage of mocking (with Rhino.Mocks), they stress all the possible features of the test framework. You way want to have a look at the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/v3/src).