# Examples of open source php projects that ship with comprehensive test coverage

Tags: php, unit-testing, magento, open-source, phpunit

There are a series of [prior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893841/open-source-projects-with-good-quality-tests) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672214/what-are-some-good-examples-of-open-source-projects-developed-in-a-test-driven-fa) that tangentially ask this question, but not directly regarding PHP, and none with actual answers, so I hope you can accommodate this iteration of the question.

It concerns me that open-source projects with large codebases and sensitive functionality (e.g. ecommerce such Magento Commerce) ship with no published unit tests.  While that doesn't necessary imply that there are no tests internally, it does mean that a team using the platform needs to develop their test coverage from scratch.

Are there examples of open source projects of reasonable size and complexity with publicly accessible test suites?

**===UPDATE===**

I'd like specifically to see examples of ***applications*** with test suites.  Frameworks and tools with tests are interesting, but I'm particularly interested in applications.  Also, could you please post any comments you might have about the quality and/or coverage of the tests provided.  Thanks!

Thanks,
JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that SilverStripe CMS (http://www.silverstripe.org/) includes a comprehensive set of [tests](https://github.com/silverstripe/sapphire/tree/master/tests), a TestRunner and considerable [documentation](http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/topics/testing/) on writing your own tests.  This is the only PHP application with that sort of coverage that I've discovered so far.

Disclaimer - I haven't used SilverStripe, so I can't comment on the quality of the framework or tests.

Answer (score 6):

- [Zeta Components](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/zetacomponents/trunk/UnitTest/src/)
- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/tests/)
- [Symfony](http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.4/test/unit/)
- [Doctrine](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/master/tests/Doctrine/Tests)

All of these come with Unit Tests

Comment: Thanks @Oktopus - do you have any comments on the quality of those tests?  Also, these are all frameworks or tools, do you know of any applications?